# Access Textbox Values to outlook mail

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Form in Access which has textbox in it. I want to input the textbox value to outlook mail body. The code I have is as follows.

```
With OutMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .Subject = "Test"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(objExcel, rng) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Form_FactorCoupon.Text25
    .Save
    .Close olPromtForSave
End With
```

`RangetoHTML(objExcel, rng)` - this function copies an excel range and paste it into mail body.

`Form_FactorCoupon.Text25` - this is the textbox in the form which contains email signature.

My issue is that `Chr(13) & Chr(10)` is not working. I used this to leave a line and then provide email signature.

How to leave a blank line and provide textbox values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use: `"<br>"` instead of `Chr(13) & Chr(10)`.

`<br>` is an HTML tag for the new line (break line), while `Chr(10)` (linefeed character) and `Chr(13)` (carriege return) are characters used to get a new line in text files (not in HTML).